# double to string conversion with fixed precision and no trailing zeros

Tags: c++, string

I have to convert a `double` value to `string`, by using a specified number of digits after the dot. However I have to avoid printing trailing zeros, so if `doubleValue` is `95`, I want to see `"95"` and not `"95.000000..."`, and similarly, if the value is `95.5`, I want to see `"95.5"` and not `"95.500000..."`.

This is my current code, using `boost::format`:

```
double doubleValue = ...;
std::string fmt = (boost::format("%%.%df") % opts.floatPrecision).str();
return (boost::format(fmt) % doubleValue).str();
```

However it does not handle the two special cases I mentioned (not printing trailing zeros, and no dot in case of int).

I guess I can remove all trailing zeros from the string, and finally remove the trailing dot if any.

But I'm asking if there is a smarter way to do it.

This is what I've done:

```
std::string fmt = (boost::format("%%.%df") % opts.floatPrecision).str();
std::string s = (boost::format(fmt) % doubleValue).str();
int len = s.length();
while(s[len - 1] == '0') len--;
if(s[len - 1] == '.') len--;
return s.substr(0, len);
```

Note: it is not mandatory to use boost, but since I use it already in my project, it comes in handy.

Comment: Just `std::ostringstream oss; oss << std::setprecision(opts.floatPrecision) << doubleValue; return oss.str()`?

Comment: what is your problem exactly are you wanting to compare doubles as a string representation? wouldn't it be more simpler if you just compared doubles with an epsilon.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: that works perfect, except the meaning of opts.floatPrecision is now "number of significative digits" instead of "digits after the dot". is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez: no I'm not doing that. I convert doubles to string for display, but I don't want to show useless trailing zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given all the issues in attempting to use a decimal format to represent a binary floating point type, if I were you, I'd adopt the following scheme:

1. Use your favourite formatter to produce a string representation of your `double`, rounded to `DBL_DIG - 1` significant figures (let the formatter do that, rather than rounding the `double` numerically).
2. Trim any excess `0` after the decimal separator yourself.

You might find this hard to believe, but your requirement is rather idiosyncratic.